# MP4 Videos won't update on the site

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, backend

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from funcs.functions import *
# import asyncio
# import .utils
# loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
app = Flask(__name__)
# import nest_asyncio
# nest_asyncio.apply()

FILE_NAMES = None


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = random_data()
        # data = random_data()
        global FILE_NAMES
        FILE_NAMES = [data['episode_1_name'], data['episode_2_name']]

        convert_episodes(data)
        return render_template("index.html")

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if FILE_NAMES is not None:
            value = submit(request.form)
            # save_csv(FILE_NAMES + [value])
            save_csv_pandas(FILE_NAMES, value)
            del_videos()

        return redirect('/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
    app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
    app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = "null"
    app.jinja_env.auto_reload = True
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the app.py. There are videos that it reads from pickle files and converts to mp4, after every button pressed or every refresh it needs to update the videos, and it does, it selects new pickle files and updates the mp4 videos but the index.html file don't get updated, it needs to get the new videos but in the site it shows the old ones, so sometimes it updates the videos, when some time passes and I refresh or press a button it updates the videos in the site, but other times it doesn't. I tried to add async/aawait to my functions like random_data and convert_episodes but it seems that the problem is not that they work slow, but somewhere else.

UPDATE: the following is the functionality I imported into the first code

```
import random
import pickle
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from cv2 import VideoWriter, VideoWriter_fourcc
import torch
import numpy as np
import imageio
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os.path
from os import path
# import asyncio

# loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def submit(form):
    if form.get("btn1"):
        return [1, 0]
    elif form.get("btn2"):
        return [0, 1]
    elif form.get("btn3"):
        return [0.5, 0.5]
    else:
        return [0, 0]


def unpickle(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as fin:
        data = pickle.load(fin)
    return data


def select_random_data(path):
    files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    rand_file_names = random.sample(files, 2)
    values = list()

    for file_name in rand_file_names:
        values.append(unpickle(path + file_name))
        values.append(file_name)

    return values


def random_data(path='../data/reward/episodes_ui/'):
    episodes_data = select_random_data(path)
    episode_1, name_1, episode_2, name_2 = episodes_data
    images_1, images_2 = episode_1['images'], episode_2['images']

    print(name_1, name_2)

    return {
        'episode_1': images_1, #np.array(torch.stack(images_1), dtype=np.uint8),
        'episode_1_name': name_1,
        'episode_2': images_2, #np.array(torch.stack(images_2), dtype=np.uint8),
        'episode_2_name': name_2,
    }


def make_video(images, name):
    # have a folder of output where output files could be stored.
    write_to = '{}.mp4'.format(name)
    writer = imageio.get_writer(write_to, format='mp4', mode='I', fps=30)
    for im in images:
        writer.append_data(im)
    writer.close()

def convert_episodes(data, path='./static/videos/'):
    for i in range(1, 3):
        name = 'episode_' + str(i)
        make_video(data[name], path + name)

def save_csv(row, path='../data/reward/targets/target.csv'):
    with open(path,'a', newline='') as f:
          writer = csv.writer(f)
          writer.writerow(row)

def save_csv_pandas(file_names, targets, file_path='../data/reward/targets/target.csv'):
    if path.exists(file_path):
        pd_dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0)
        if len(list(pd_dataframe.dropna()['target_1'])) >= 200:
            pd_dataframe = pd_dataframe.drop([0])
        dataframe = {'episode_1': file_names[0], 'episode_2': file_names[1], 'target_1': targets[0], 'target_2': targets[1]}
        pd_dataframe = pd_dataframe.append(dataframe, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        dataframe = {'episode_1': file_names[0], 'episode_2': file_names[1], 'target_1': targets[0], 'target_2': targets[1]}
        pd_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dataframe, index=[0])


    pd_dataframe.to_csv(file_path)

def del_videos():

    for i in range(1, 3):
        name = 'episode_' + str(i) + '.mp4'
        os.remove('./static/videos/' + name)
```

Comment: Please fix you indentation and provide the code if the functions called.

Comment: @KlausD. I did, take a look

Comment: Does the issue persist when you refresh while clearing cache? Either open a new incognito window or Ctrl + F5

Comment: @big_bad_bison same thing